# Using Model in routes file, cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2

I am looking to load values from my database in my /app/Config/routes.php configuration file.

At the top I am using: `App::uses('Option', 'Model');`

And I am calling my find in my class: `$this->Option->find('all');`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* you have to instantiate the model before you use it:

```
App::uses('Option', 'Model');
$option = new Option();
$something = $option->find('all');
```

Comment: Gracias. Seems to get me closer. I'm not getting an error about my missing object. But I do get a `Cannot redeclare class DATABASE_CONFIG ` error

Comment: Strange, I just checked and I have used exactly that on a project, and it worked. Are you by any chance including `database.php` from `routes.php`? That could cause the error you're seeing (because that class is declare at database.php).

Comment: @alairock Actually, I just updated my answer to an equivalent of what I used on my project. Try not using `$this`.

Comment: bingo. App::uses('Option', 'Model'); already contains an include  Without realizing it, I actually did have it included again in my routes file, which wasn't an issue until I needed to load a model. Thanks!

Comment: How we do it in cakephp 3.6?

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't put any database queries in Routes. It's not the place for them (separation of concerns etc). It will also slow down every request and the routes shouldn't be changing all that frequently.

What I've done is to create a routes file in app/tmp/cache every time a database route is created/updated (your code will be different but this is how I do it).

In your route model:

```
function rebuildCache() {

    $data = $this->find('all');

    $buffer = "<?php\n";

    $filename = TMP . 'cache' . DS . 'routes.php';

    foreach($data as $item) {

        $url = Router::parse('/' . $item['Route']['destination']);

        if (count($url['pass']) > 0) {

            $id = $url['pass'][count($url['pass']) - 1];

        }
        else {

            $id = null;

        }

        $buffer .= "Router::connect('/{$item['Route']['url']}', array('controller'=>'{$url['controller']}', 'action'=>'{$url['action']}', {$id}));\n";

    }

    file_put_contents($filename, $buffer);

}
```

Call rebuildCache() from your route model afterSave():

```
function afterSave() {

    $this->rebuildCache();  

}
```

Simply include the file in Routes.php:

```
$routes_cache_filename = TMP . 'cache' . DS . 'routes.php';

if (file_exists($routes_cache_filename)) {

    require_once $routes_cache_filename;

}
```

Comment: how I call afterSave function form Config/routes.php

Answer (score 0):

```
  /*Load ClassRegistry*/
   App::uses('ClassRegistry', 'Utility');
  /**
   * Initialize model and perform find
   */
  $Cms = ClassRegistry::init('Cms'); 
  $cmsdata = $Cms->find('all'); 

  /**
   * Iterate over results and define routes
   */
  foreach ($cmsdata as $cmsrow) {
    Router::connect('/', array('controller' => $cmsrow['Cms']['controller'], 'action' => $cmsrow['Cms']['slug']));
  }
```