# CakePHP catch all route

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

I have run into an issue that I am sure it just from me being fairly rusty with cake. I am trying to create a default or catch-all route that will only match if all other routes have failed. I assumed from my understand of most MVC frameworks that something like the following would be sufficient:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
#... other routes
Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'dynamic_display', 'home'));
CakePlugin::routes();
require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

The problem with this is that the `Router::connect('/*')` route causes a conflict with previous routes. I have also tried a "slug" route but I have the same issue with the conflicts.

Are there any solutions to this issue or a possible work around?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

In my comment below I linked to a comment that provided a decent solution to my problem. Here is my simple proof of concept.

Page.php

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

/**
 * Page model
 * @uses AppModel
 */
    class Page extends AppModel {
        /**
         * MongoDB Schema definitions
         *
         * @var array 'mongoSchema'
         * @link https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/
         */
            var $mongoSchema = array(
                'title'=>array('type'=>'string'),
                'meta_description'=>array('type'=>'text'),
                'slug'=>array('type'=>'string'),
                'content'=>array('type'=>'text'),
                'published'=>array('type'=>'bool'),
                'created'=>array('type'=>'datetime'),
            );

        /**
         * afterSave method. 
         * @return void
         */
            public function afterSave($created, $options=array()) {
                $this->__rebuildRouteCache();
            }

        /**
         * rebuild route cache method. This will rewrite the routes for our simple CMS each time a page is added or updated
         * @return void
         */
            private function __rebuildRouteCache() {
                $pages = $this->find('all');
                $filename = TMP . 'cache' . DS . 'routes.php';
                $buffer = "<?php \r\n";

                foreach($pages as $page) {
                    $buffer .= 'Router::connect("'. $page['Page']['slug'] .'", array( "controller" => "pages", "action" => "dynamic_display"));';
                    $buffer .= "\r\n";
                }

                $buffer .= "?>";

                file_put_contents($filename, $buffer);
            }



    }
?>
```

routes.php

```
<?php
#..snip
/**
 * Include our route cache if it exists
 */
    $fname = TMP . 'cache' . DS . 'routes.php';
    if(file_exists($fname)) {
        require_once $fname;
    }


/**
 * Load all plugin routes. See the CakePlugin documentation on
 * how to customize the loading of plugin routes.
 */
    CakePlugin::routes();

/**
 * Load the CakePHP default routes. Only remove this if you do not want to use
 * the built-in default routes.
 */
    require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
?>
```

This is not a catch all route like I wanted but it is a workable solution for my situation. Hopefully this will be useful for someone else as well.

Comment: [This comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12316219/4425082) offers a nice solution to my problem. I can write a new routes.php each time I add a dynamic page or change a slug.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';` you are basically including cakephp default routes that are already catch-all routes. Routes configured through this line are among all:

```
Router::connect('/:controller', array('action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/:controller/:action/*');
```

All the routes you defined in `#... other routes` should still be working.

However, if you were using Cakephp default routes in your app, they are now overrided by your custom "catch-all" route.

Answer (score 0):

Create one function inside AppController.php as given below.

```
public function appError($error) {
    $this->redirect('/catch-all-route',301,false);
}
```

The above function will catch all the error pages which doesn't have been in routes.php

Now create one rule for `/catch-all-route`

```
Router::connect('/catch-all-route', 
 array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'dynamic_display', 'home'));
```

This way you can match all the urls which are not defined in routes.php