# Writing automatic routes in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, router

As I can write my own automatic routes using the `Router :: connect 2x CakePHP`?
I need write my routes in the database and pass parameters to routes.php file with my database, to make a  friendly URL.

I have something like this (but I have to do it by hand):

```
Router :: connect ('/ Mycity / gifts / *', array ('controller' => 'shops', 'action' => 'result', 'F', null, '1', '4'));
```

I need something like this (to automate processes):

```
Router::connect('/'.$city.'/'.$shop.'/*',array('controller'=>'shops','action'=>'result','.$genre.',null,'1','4'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to instantiate your objects (more info [Using Model in routes file, cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310953/using-model-in-routes-file-cakephp) )

```
// City model
App::uses('City', 'Model');
$cityModel = new City();
$cities = $cityModel->find('all');
// Shop model
App::uses('Shop', 'Model');
$shopModel = new Shop();
$shops = $shopModel->find('all');
```

Then you can loop through them and create dynamic routes

```
foreach ($cities as $city) {
    foreach ($shops as $shop) {
        Router::connect(/* your params */);
    }
}
```

But be careful, if there is so many records it could faster to just query if combination of shop and city exists and if so, then just create this one route.

Comment: Thanks Bro!, But  finally i Wrote directly the router.php archive, with Fwrite property from Php, is less code.